# How can I provide a suffix icon, in FLUTTER, that a user can tap when the form field has errors and it shows the error on tapping in a toot-tip

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

What I need is a error builder, so that the input component can change its appearance and display required information in case of any error,

I am using it like this in the widget tree

FORM>>COLUMN>>CHILDREN>CONTAINER>>DECORATION WITH BG COLOR>>CHILD>TEXT FORM FIELD > NO FILLED COLOR>INPUT DECORATION > LABEL TEXT > SUFFIX ICON

THE FORM FIELD HAVE A VALIDATOR TOO !

Answer (score 1):

- Suffix icon is a `Widget`. So it can be anything, like `Container`, `InkWell`, `GestureDetector`... You can use InkWell(onTap: ..., child: icon).
- You can use Stream (`StreamBuilder`) to detect error. If it is not valid, then sink error value to stream. `StreamBuilder` will listen to the error value, and do something.

Good luck!